# ChartJS different length labels arrays for different datasets on the same chart

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs-2

I want to have N "places" for my line points and N-1 "places" for my bars, but all I am getting for now is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0h23F.png)

Basically I want my bars to be in-between x axis, and my points to be on x axis like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOc4g.png)

I tried reading the docs and playing with labels/datasets but had no luck with that. I believe it is possible to fix this problem by "cheating" and shifting/resizing my bars so they fit better, but I'd like to know if there's a cleaner solution.

Dunno if that'll be helpful, but here's my axis options and related chart data:

```
      x: { display: false },
      x1: {
        type: "category",
        grid: {
          drawOnChartArea: false,
        },
        display: true,
      },
```

```
    labels: [1, 2],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: Temperature,
        data: [19, 20],
        type: "line",
      },
      {
        label: "Precipitation",
        data: [2],
        type: "bar",
        xAxisID: "x1",
      },
```